# Adding System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser to System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel cannot convert to System.Windows.UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, webbrowser-control, uielement

I need to add `WebBrowser` control to dynamically generated `Window` in WPF application.

Basically when agent clicks on the link I need to open the `webbrowser` window that has close (X) button disabled (or hidden) on some pages and not on others. Reason is they get redirected to 3rd party payment system that collects the payment and if they close browser window after collecting the payment but before they are redirected back  to our system we do not get notification of payment being collected while 3rd party charges our customers.

Originally web browser window was opened in `Windows.Form`, but I was unable to find a way to disable X on Form, so figured to switch to WPF Window since our app is WPF in the first place, so I introduced window and panel but now when dynamically adding `WebBrowser` control to panel `Children` it gives following error

> Error cannot convert from
>   'Desktop.ViewModels.PaymentViewModel.NavigateToTakePaymentCommand.MyWebBrowser'
>   to 'System.Windows.UIElement'

```
private void OpenBrowser(PaymentViewModel viewModel, Uri uri)
{
   viewModel.BrowserWindow = new WithoutCloseButton();
   viewModel.BrowserWindow.Closed += BrowserWindow_Closed;
   var browser = new MyWebBrowser();
   var stackPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical };
  stackPanel.Children.Add(browser); // this bit fails
  viewModel.BrowserWindow.Content = stackPanel;
```

...

```
public class WithoutCloseButton : Window
{
    private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    private const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
}

public class MyWebBrowser : System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
{
    public static Guid IID_IHttpSecurity
        = new Guid("79eac9d7-bafa-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b");
    public static Guid IID_IWindowForBindingUI
        = new Guid("79eac9d5-bafa-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b");
    public const int S_OK = 0;
    public const int S_FALSE = 1;
    public const int E_NOINTERFACE = unchecked((int)0x80004002);
    public const int RPC_E_RETRY = unchecked((int)0x80010109);
    protected override WebBrowserSiteBase CreateWebBrowserSiteBase()
    {
        return new MyWebBrowserSite(this);
    }

    class MyWebBrowserSite : WebBrowserSite, UCOMIServiceProvider,IHttpSecurity, IWindowForBindingUI
    {
        private MyWebBrowser myWebBrowser;
        public MyWebBrowserSite(MyWebBrowser myWebBrowser) : base(myWebBrowser)
        {
            this.myWebBrowser = myWebBrowser;
        }

        public int QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvObject)
        {
            if (riid == IID_IHttpSecurity)
            {
                ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this
                    , typeof(IHttpSecurity));
                return S_OK;
            }
            if (riid == IID_IWindowForBindingUI)
            {
                ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this
                    , typeof(IWindowForBindingUI));
                return S_OK;
            }
            ppvObject = IntPtr.Zero;
            return E_NOINTERFACE;
        }

        public int GetWindow(ref Guid rguidReason , ref IntPtr phwnd)
        {
            if (rguidReason == IID_IHttpSecurity || rguidReason == IID_IWindowForBindingUI)
            {
                phwnd = myWebBrowser.Handle;
                return S_OK;
            }
            else
            {
                phwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
                return S_FALSE;
            }
        }

        public int OnSecurityProblem(uint dwProblem)
        {
            //ignore errors
            //undocumented return code, does not work on IE6
            return S_OK;
        }
    }
}
```

How to add `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` to `System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel`? Is there like a wrapper on something?

Comment: You need to use System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx or host the Windows Forms browser into a WPF control somehow.

Comment: as for the wrapper, check this out: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-windowsformshost-control/

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex Hi, thanks for answer. System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowsr is sealed I cannot inherit it

Comment: WPF is more about composition than inheritance. Anyway, the WebBrowser control is a mess and if you have solved problems with the Windows.Forms one, maybe you need to use that one hosted in WPF.

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex hey thanks, that tutorial looks promising. Indeed it's one of those choices between genocide and plague...

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex made it work - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @Siderite Zackwehdex

I had to add reference to `WindowsFormsIntegration`. Go to project and expand `References` -> `Add Reference` -> `Assemblies` -> `Framework` -> tick `WindowsFormsIntegration`.

[image]

Then I had to change the following bits.

```
public class WithoutCloseButton : Window
        {
            private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
            private const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;

            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

//THIS IS NEW
            public void HideButtons()
            {
                var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
                SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_SYSMENU);
            }
        }
```

and then in `OpenBrowser()` I had to wrap `WebBrowser` in `WindowsFormsHost`

```
 private void OpenBrowser(PaymentViewModel viewModel, Uri uri)
 {
    viewModel.BrowserWindow = new WithoutCloseButton();
    viewModel.BrowserWindow.Closed += BrowserWindow_Closed;
    var browser = new MyWebBrowser();
    var stackPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical };
    var formsHost = new WindowsFormsHost {Child = browser};
    stackPanel.Children.Add(formsHost);
    viewModel.BrowserWindow.Content = stackPanel;
//....    then            
 browser.Navigate("about:blank");
 browser.DocumentCompleted += delegate(object obj, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.ToString() == "about:blank")
    {
        ((MyWebBrowser)obj).Navigate(uri);
    }

    if (e.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("accepted"))
    {
        ViewModel.AuthCode = this.GetAuthToken();
        ViewModel.updateUiWhenDoneWithPayment_RunWorkerCompleted(new object(), null);
        ViewModel.BrowserWindow.Close();
        ViewModel.BrowserWindow = null;
    }
    //THIS IS NEW
    if (e.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("payment/confirmation"))
    {
        viewModel.BrowserWindow.HideButtons();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To add `Window` `Form` `controls` in `WPF` you need [WindowsFormsHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(v=vs.110).aspx) first. Add `WindowsFormHost` to your `StackPanel` and then add your `webbrowser` to `WindowsFormHost`. `XAML` examples are below:

1.

```
    <WindowsFormsHost>
        <wf:MaskedTextBox x:Name="mtbDate" Mask="00/00/0000"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
```

2.

```
   <wfh:WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="wbFormHost" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TabIndex="6">
        <wf:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" x:FieldModifier="public" Dock="Fill"/>
    </wfh:WindowsFormsHost>
```

where `wfh` is `xmlns:wfh="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"`